# App review says Login button does not work

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-apps

I am working on a project that needs a permission for user_link. Functionality that implements this feature is currently implemented on https://staging.meetmeinthe.bar/. I have fixed all of our bugs and made our app comply fully with the requirements. But, for some reason, one of FB reviewers keeps declining our submission, saying that our Login button does not work. We have tested our login functionality many times from multiple devices - it works. Why do we keep getting rejected? Any advices are welcome.

When you land on a web page, you should click orange "Login" button in the top-right corner to see it.

[image]

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to contact support that verified the fact that everything was working correctly.